# Is there a way to create a PNG image of a graph using pyvis module?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, pyvis

I wonder if there is a way to export a network to PNG using pyvis, or whether there is a workaround to quickly convert html to png.

So far I've found the networkx class Visual, but the networkx graph implementation seems a bit more complicated than the pyvis one.

Comment: Are you asking for a suggestion for a library because that would be off-topic?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PrakharRathi nope, mostly I'd just want to know whether it is possible to somehow export graph to png using that specific library (pyvis).